# How can I use a web proxy with CURLOPT_PROXY

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am trying to find a way to install a reverse proxy on my webhost that can be used later with CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'mywebproxy:80')
```

Creating a normal proxy require at least root access to the server to use (nginx, squid, etc) or a server module (apache mod_proxy), which is not available for me at my web-hosting service.

Is there any pre created projects like this I can re write for me, I don't want to re invent the wheel

Comment: _"So what are my options"_ Well, for starters, you can edit your post to include a more specific question. We're not genies, who can spit up every method/way to go about this. But what we _can_ do is answer questions with specific code/issues. Your question is very broad and is off-topic according to [S/O rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AaronGillion Thank you, is now better ?